# Save file when closing Blender

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using WinForms. I got `open_button` to open Blender ("Process" class) and `close_button` to close. How to save changes that was made in blender on `close_button` click?

Comment: Check out _Microsoft UI Automation_.  Though originally a UI automated testing system, it is also the preferred method for _remote-controlling_ apps without having to have the app expose an API

Answer (score 1):

The concept of the C# `Process` class and the action like *Save* don't fit together. If you want to remote control Blender, you need an API, e.g. a COM object which would then have methods that allow saving. You can e.g. control Word and Excel like that.

AFAIK Blender is implemented in C/C++ and has a Python interface, but no C# API. So either you build it yourself or you switch to Python.

Another option would be UI automation (i.e. identifying UI elements and actually performing mouse clicks or similar), but that can become tedious and needs adaptation each time Blender changes their UI. It typically works bad if you need to interact with the 3D view and has timing issues.

Yet another way would be to build your own version of Blender from its source code and always save when exiting.